# Probability of n basketball teams

Tags: probability

$n$ basketball teams are given, $T_1,...,T_n$. Every pair $T_i, T_j$ plays a single game (note: the number of games is $n \choose 2$). A game between $T_i, T_j$ either ends with $T_i$ winning or with $T_j$ winning (no ties). Show that there is a way to arrange the teams on a line as $T_{i_1}, T_{i_2}$ lost to $T_{i_3}$ and so on until $T_{i_(n-1)}$ that lost to $T_{i_n}$

I don't quite understand how to do this problem, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is clear if there are just two teams.

Now suppose you have $n>2$ teams and that you are able to do it for every set of $m$ teams with $m<n$.

If one of the teams lost every game, there is no problem: line up the remaining $n-1$ considering only the games between them and prepend the always losing team to the line.

Similarly if one of the teams won every game: line up the remaining teams as before and append the always winning team to the line.

If there is no all loser or all winner, pick up a team at random, and call it $T$. Let $L$ be the set of teams that lost to $T$ and $W$ the set of teams which won over $T$.

Both sets are formed by less than $n$ teams, so they can be lined up in the prescribed way considering only the games between them (if any of these sets is a singleton, there's no line up problem, of course). Now concatenate the line up from $L$, insert team $T$, then append the line up from $W$.